Python: расчёт параметров полёта в другую звёздную систему и обратно
Базируясь на расчётах Станислава Володарского (см. ниже) вроде бы удалось построить некую теорию и написать скрипт для расчёта:
'''
Задача: экспедиция стартует из Солнечной системы в другую звёздную систему с постоянным ускорением. Первую часть пути корабль ускоряется,
вторую часть пути летит по инерции, третью часть пути тормозится (с тем же ускорением, но отрицательным, и на таком же участке пути).
К моменту прибытия в другую звёздную систему скорость корабля равна 0. Далее - путь домой, точно по такой же схеме.
Вычислить время полёта туда и обратно в земной системе отсчёта, время полёта туда и обратно в системе отсчёта корабля, максимальную скорость корабля.
'''

import os
import math

print("-" * 65 + "\nРасчёт параметров полёта в другую звёздную систему и обратно:\n" + "-" * 65)

c = 1  # скорость света: 1 световой год / год
a = 2  # ускорение корабля: 1 световой год / год ** 2 = 9,5 м / c ** 2 (близко к значению ускорения свободного падения на поверхности Земли)
star = "Фомальгаут"
l = 25  # расстояние до звёздной системы (световых лет)
l_a = l * 0.1  # расстояние, пройденное в режиме разгона (торможения) в одну сторону (световых лет)
l_i = l * 0.8  # расстояние, пройденное в режиме движения по инерции  в одну сторону (световых лет)

# время разгона (торможения) в одну сторону в земной системе отсчёта (лет)
t1 = c / a * math.sqrt((a * l_a / c ** 2 + 1) ** 2 - 1)

# время разгона (торможения) в одну сторону в системе отсчёта корабля (лет)
t2 = (c / a) * math.asinh(a * t1 / c)

# максимальная скорость корабля, которую удалось достичь (долей скорости света)
v = c * math.tanh(math.asinh(a * t1 / c))

# время движения по инерции в одну сторону в земной системе отсчёта (лет)
t1_i = l_i / v

# время движения по инерции в одну сторону в системе отсчёта корабля (лет)
t2_i = t1_i * math.sqrt(1 - (v / c) ** 2)

# общее время полёта в земной системе отсчёта (лет)
t1_full = 4 * t1 + 2 * t1_i

# общее время полёта в системе отсчёта корабля (лет)
t2_full = 4 * t2 + 2 * t2_i

# Вывод результатов
print(f"Звёздная система: {star}")
print(f"Расстояние до звёздной системы (световых лет): {l: .2f}")
print(f"Ускорение корабля (световых лет / (год ** 2)): {a: .2f}")
print(f"Расстояние, пройденное в режиме разгона (торможения) туда и обратно (в %): {4 * l_a / l: .2%}")
print(f"Расстояние, пройденное в режиме движения по инерции туда и обратно (в %): {2 * l_i / l: .2%}")
print(f"Время полёта туда и обратно в земной системе отсчёта (лет): {t1_full: .2f}")
print(f"Время полёта туда и обратно в системе отсчёта корабля (лет): {t2_full: .2f}")
print(f"Максимальная скорость корабля (% от скорости света): {v: .2%}")

print("\nНажмите любую клавишу для продолжения...")
os.system("pause > nul")

Вот результат:
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Расчёт параметров полёта в другую звёздную систему и обратно:
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Звёздная система: Фомальгаут
Расстояние до звёздной системы (световых лет):  25.00
Ускорение корабля (световых лет / (год ** 2)):  2.00
Расстояние, пройденное в режиме разгона (торможения) туда и обратно (в %):  40.00%
Расстояние, пройденное в режиме движения по инерции туда и обратно (в %):  160.00%
Время полёта туда и обратно в земной системе отсчёта (лет):  52.40
Время полёта туда и обратно в системе отсчёта корабля (лет):  11.72
Максимальная скорость корабля (% от скорости света):  98.60%


Хочу добавить ещё, что есть на свете шедевр фантастики, называющийся "Возвращение со звёзд" (С.Лем). Там, по сюжету, экспедиция летела к Фомальгауту (25 световых лет) с ускорением 2 G  и обратно. По внутренним часам у них прошло 10 лет, а на Земле прошло 127 лет. Этот мой алгоритм выдаёт ну совершенно другое. Очень хочется понять, кто прав - Лем или я.

Плохо помню эту тему, но мне кажется, что нужно посчитать время (с т.з. земного наблюдателя (вы же в функции расчета оперируете наблюдаемыми с Земли показателями?)), когда будет достигнута скорость 0.99с (или половина дистанции (что раньше)) и отталкиваться от этого пункта. Если достигнута скорость 0.99с до достижения полпути, то наверное логично считать, что остаток летим с постоянной скоростью. А время прошедшее  в ракете надо постоянно пересчитывать (и считать его сумму (вообще правильно будет интегрировать)) по мере роста скорости (естественно, начиная с какой-то достаточно большой).

Спасибо. Я мало что понял, но попробую проанализировать Ваши утверждения. Понимаете, в чём проблема. Не достигаем мы 0.99c. После деления на gamma остаётся около 42 тыс. км/сек. Я терзал автора теории насчёт этого и он меня долго убеждал, но не убедил. Вот потому и пишу сюда. Получается у него, что разогнаться до 0.99с вообще невозможно.

Замедление времени рассчитывается для максимальной скорости а применяется ко всему полёту, хотя большую часть времени мы летим медленнее. Ограничение в 0.99c вообще никуда не годится. Время разгона рассчитано по формуле для равноускоренного движения. Но движение не равноускоренное.

@StanislavVolodarskiy, наверное, если принять постоянную мощность двигателя, то ускорение с т.з. экипажа будет постоянным, а вот для наблюдателя с Земли оно будет падать, пропорционально растущей массе ракеты? (я правильно вспоминаю основы СТО?)

@avp, верно. Из формулы Лоренца для сложения скоростей можно вывести дифференциальное уравнение для ускорения при равноускоренном движении (и, как вы верно заметили, с ростом скорости ускорение падает). Интегрируя ускорение получим скорость, интегрируя её получим расстояние.

Уравнение можете написать? Я б его запрограммировал потом.

Вот ваша задача: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5 — посмотрите там собственное время... Находится с полпинка запросом типа "Время полета при постоянном ускорении релятивистская задача". Вы вообще пытались хоть что-то искать, или не царское это дело - в Гугле ковыряться, прикажу в ruSO — найдут!

Супер! Сейчас поизучаю, а потом попробую сделать утилитку на Питоне. Что касается поисков, то пытался даже немного больше, видимо, не достаточно, но здесь эта тема непопулярна в качестве обсуждения.

Я сосчитал полёт без участка по инерции и с ним (0.6 расстояния по инерции). Без участка корабельное время 7.26, с участком 8.22. То есть, экономия - один год работы двигателя из восьми. Это означает, полёты по инерции, скорее всего, имеют мало смысла. Вы или выигрываете очень мало, или участок по инерции должен быть очень длинным.

Это уже из серии о реальности полёта. Двигатель, который может работать постоянно, это фантастика даже в фантастике. Я, кстати, выбрал ускорение, равное 1G приблизительно, не случайно. Таким образом можно избежать губительного влияния невесомости. Что касается полёта, описанного в произведении Лема, то получить 10 лет полёта в корабле, 127 лет на Земле и ускорение 2G, с помощью этой теории трудновато. Похоже, что числа писатель взял с потолка.

У меня к Вам,  Stanislav Volodarskiy, такой вопрос. В последнем варианте расчёта путь разбивается на 6 частей - разгон, инерция, торможение - и обратно то же. Если объединить эти участки по типу и считать каждый тип как одно целое, результаты получатся совсем другие. Что тут не так?

Если вы объединили два разгона вместе, второй разгон начнётся со скорости набранной в первом разгоне. Вы пролетите за время второго разгона гораздо большее расстояние. Вы получите большую скорость в конце второго разгона, влияние релятивистских поправок усилится. Нет, переставлять участки траектории нельзя даже в классической механике, тем более в СТО.

Спасибо. Я так и думал. Правильно вычислять, когда на участке движения либо стартовая скорость, либо конечная равна 0.

Вычисления с ненулевой стартовой скорость возможны, но требуется усложнить формулы. Если хотите можно отдельно решить задачу для произвольного набора равноускоренных движений.

Эта мысль уже часа два бродит в голове. В идеале было бы интересно иметь универсальную функцию для обработки участков полёта. На входе - длина участка пути, стартовая скорость в его начале и ускорение. Если стартовая скорость 0, так формула упрощается, если ускорение ноль, то получается равномерное релятивистское движение, если ускорение отрицательно, то замедление. А на выходе - время на Земле и время на борту. Но эта физика мне не по зубам. Честно говоря, и физику этого варианта я не сочинял ни разу. Именно поэтому и потерял время в начале исследования. Я умею адаптировать формулы в код.

Мой приятель уже подсуетил мне модель движения на участке, где на вход подаётся длина участка, начальная скорость и ускорение, а на выходе - время по корабельным часам и время на Земле. Однако, я оценить качество математики не могу.

import math

print("-" * 50 + "\nРасчёт времени полёта до другой звёздной системы:\n" + "-" * 50)

d = 4.3  # расстояние до звёздной системы в световых годах
c = 1 # скорость света: 1 световой год / год
a = 1 # ускорение: 1 световой год / год^2 = 9,5 м/c^2 (близко к значению ускорения свободного падения на повержности Земли)
d1 = d / 2  # половина пути в одну сторону

# земное время достижения половины расстояния
t1 = ((d1 * a / c ** 2 + 1) ** 2 - 1) ** 0.5 * c / a

# скорость по окончании разгона - максимальная скорость
u1 = a * t1 / (1 + (a * t1 / c) ** 2) ** 0.5

# корабельное время по окончании разгона - половина корабельного времени полета
tau1 = c / a * math.log((1 + (a * t1 / c) ** 2) ** 0.5 + a * t1 / c)

# Расчёт времени полёта в земной системе отсчёта:
t_earth = 2 * t1

# Расчёт времени в системе отсчёта корабля:
t_ship = 2 * tau1

# Вывод результатов
print(f"Расстояние до звёздной системы (световых лет): {d:.2f}")
print(f"Ускорение корабля (световых лет / (год ^ 2)): {a:.2f}")
print(f"Время полёта в одну сторону в земной системе отсчёта (лет): {t_earth:.2f}")
print(f"Время полёта в одну сторону по часам на корабле: {t_ship:.2f} лет")
print(f"Максимальная скорость корабля: {u1:.2%} от скорости света")


$ python starship.py
--------------------------------------------------
Расчёт времени полёта до другой звёздной системы:
--------------------------------------------------
Расстояние до звёздной системы (световых лет): 4.30
Ускорение корабля (световых лет / (год ^ 2)): 1.00
Время полёта в одну сторону в земной системе отсчёта (лет): 5.97
Время полёта в одну сторону по часам на корабле: 3.63 лет
Максимальная скорость корабля: 94.83% от скорости света



Похоже на результат. Но я пока не понимаю, почему так резко отличается от формул в Википедии. Я текст изменил - сделал полёт туда и обратно и добавил участок движения по инерции. Попробую поразбираться, но сомневаюсь, что без теории пойму откуда что берётся.

Все формулы из Википедии.

Всё таки хотелось бы ссылки. Я сделал свой вариант по тем ссылкам, которые дал Harry. Да, я не уверен, что понял всё, потому и тему постоянно мониторю. Но Ваш код как-то уж сильно отличается...

Думаю, Ваше правильнее. Я не могу понять пока вот это: t1 = ((d1 * a / c ** 2 + 1) ** 2 - 1) ** 0.5 * c / a

Мои формулы из той же ссылки. t1 = ... это обращение формулы x(t) = .... Она так устроена, что t там только в одном месте. Так что её легко обратить. По половине расстояния до звезды восстанавливается время разгона (земное). По времени разгона вычисляется скорость в конце разгона. По земному времени t вычисляется корабельное tau.

Нет, Вы уж извините, я не такой умный, чтоб понять хоть слово. Всё таки надо чувствовать аудиторию, её возможности. Я нашёл в сети недостающую формулу. Она об этом: "основная формула, используемая для расчета времени в земной системе отсчета при постоянном ускорении".  После неё я уже приблизительно понимаю, что всё нужное на одной странице, а другая - о замедлении времени - неизвестно о чём и как. Хотя именно там описана задача буквально. Это меня и сбило с толку. Я засчитываю Ваш ответ как ответ, хотя и не могу утверждать это на все сто ибо не шарю как надо. Спасибо.

Читать, конечно, тяжеловато. Может оно и правильно писать a ** 0.5 вместо math.sqrt(a), но в данном случае превращает формулы в дурдом. Извините.

@FoxFox, в этой задаче разницы между a ** 0.5 и math.sqrt(a) нет. Первое, на мой взгляд читается легче. В обычном программировании всегда предпочитаю math.sqrt(a).

Что-то я не очень понимаю, что вы там считаете, как именно вы учитываете релятивистские эффекты. Есть ссылка на текст, где эти формулы можно посмотреть?
А с самим полётом основная проблема в том, что время полёта вы считаете чисто на основе величины ускорения. То, что вы физически не можете в реальности разогнаться даже до 0.9 скорости света, вы не учитываете. Я посмотрел, у вас там максимальная скорость в середине пути получается 441 тыс.км/с, такого в реальности достичь нельзя, конечно. И не только из-за физического ограничения на максимальную скорость физических частиц, которая равняется скорости света, но и ещё из-за того, что чем больше вы хотите разогнаться, тем больше (экспоненциально больше) нужно будет прикладывать усилий. Просто невозможно иметь столько топлива на ракете, чтобы так разогнаться.
В общем, задайте максимальную скорость как хотя бы 0.9c (а реалистичнее 0.7c, например), а потом посчитайте, сколько времени займёт разгон до этой скорости, ну и в результате у вас будет три участка пути:

разгон до максимальной скорости
движение на максимальной скорости
торможение до нулевой скорости
И это даже ещё без учёта релятивистских эффектов, которые надо ещё подумать, как тут вообще применить.

А то, что вы там взяли 0.99c за максимум, так до этой скорости разгоняются только протоны в ускорителе, да и то с большим трудом и специальными ухищрениями. Разогнать до этой скорости физическое тело наших масштабов, а не маленькую частицу - задача просто не реальная.
В общем, возможно, у вас даже и не сильно больше время полёта будет после пересчёта, но тут нужно всё-таки смотреть формулы, сколько понадобится энергии при разгоне ракеты до больших скоростей. Скорее всего там будет получаться, что просто не реально продолжать разгоняться тем же темпом при достижении какой-то скорости. Даже имея большие запасы топлива. Чем больше скорость, тем больше потребуется энергии на дополнительный разгон. Скорее всего, все расчёты поэтому обычно ограничивают какой-то небольшой скоростью, из-за этого ракета и должна долго лететь.

Ну, представим, что у автора двигатель неограниченной (но регулируемой) мощности и неограниченный запас рабочего тела (можно даже представить, что оно берется из параллельного пространства). Тогда остается только предел в виде скорости света. Вот к такой модели и надо применять формулы (кои я плохо помню). И еще, насколько помню, все даваемые нам еще в школе формулы СТО относятся к движению с постоянной скоростью, а у автора движение с ускорением. Наверное для этого случая надо искать какие-то модифицированные формулы (или моделировать такое движение как ряд интервалов с постоянной скоростью)

CrazyElf, Вы напутали, нет вот этого: 441 тыс.км/с, есть вот это: 41868.02. Я тоже примерно так думаю, как avp, но я бы хотел увидеть эту математическую модель. Полагаю, пока можно оставить в стороне "это нереально" и рассмотреть голую матмодель. Я пытаюсь понять в каком месте или местах надо применять преобразования Лоренца. При таком движении и масса увеличивается, и расстояния сжимаются, и время сжимается. Надо понять, где в формулах движения умножать или делить на gamma. Я также думаю, что это всё вообще неправильно, надо работать с каждой секундой движения в цикле.

Давайте подумаем.  В начале скорость ноль. Через секунду - 10 м/с, через две - 20 м/сек и т.д. По большому счёту релятивистские эффекты начинают работать сразу, просто при маленькой скорости они мизерны. Время по корабельным часам уже отличается от земного, а расстояние (вот тут я плохо понимаю, что за расстояние) уже меньше. В следующую секунду скорость прирастает и опять релятивистские эффекты работают. Я не вижу, что неравномерное движение тут вообще чем-то мешает. Скорость должна расти постоянно. Просто преобразования Лоренца не должны позволить значению скорости превысить 300 тыс.

Я не понимаю, как в этой всей кутерьме вычислять времена и пройденное расстояние. Подозреваю, что надо где-то делить или умножать на текущее значение gamma, но не вижу стройной модели.
